# Javascript onchange validation so that :valid and :invalid CSS selectors work

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I have not been able to find anything about this.

How can I use something like the following:

```
// html: <input type="text" onchange="validate()">
function validate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(isValid(this.value)) {
        // make valid somehow
    } else {
        // make invalid somehow
    }
}
```

so that the following CSS works as you might expect:

```
input:valid {
    background: green;
}

input:invalid {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Click "Run code snippet" to see!**

You can create a custom validator and use the `setCustomValidity` function on the element to allow use of these selectors.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Complex_constraints_using_HTML5_Constraint_API) describes how to use the HTML5 Constraint API to achieve this.

## Example:

```css
#inputField:valid {
  background-color: green;
}

#inputField:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Type a value (must be 'abc'): <input id="inputField">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function validateField() {
        if (this.value !== 'abc') {
          this.setCustomValidity('Value must be abc!');
        }
        else {
          this.setCustomValidity('');
        }
      }
      window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("inputField").oninput= validateField;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
// html: <input type="text" onchange="validate()">
function validate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = e.target

    if(isValid(this.value)) {
        target.classList.add("valid")
        target.classList.remove("invalid")
    } else {
        target.classList.remove("valid")
        target.classList.add("invalid")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateField(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = event.currentTarget
  if (target.value != "" || target.value.length > 0) {
    target.classList.remove("invalidFunction");
    target.classList.add("validFunction");
  } else {
    target.classList.add("invalidFunction");
    target.classList.remove("validFunction");
  }
};
```

```css
.invalidFunction {
  border-color: red;
}

.validFunction{
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
Field is mandatory:

<input id="inputFunctionField" onchange="validateField(event)">
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just use css classes if you wish (and I added the syntax for using jquery to addclasses and remove classes but can also be done in pure javascript)..

```
input.valid {
  background: green;
}

input.invalid {
  background: red;
}

function validate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    if(isValid(this.value)) {
       $(this).removeClass("invalid");
       $(this).addClass("valid");
    } else {
       $(this).removeClass("valid");
       $(this).addClass("invalid");
        // make invalid somehow
    }
}
```

none jquery (assuming there is no other classes currently used. as this seems like the html you have, if there are additional classes just manipulate the string to add and remove the relevant class).

```
function validate(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        if(isValid(this.value)) {
           this.className = "valid"
        } else {
           this.className = "invalid"
            // make invalid somehow
        }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, `removeClass()` and `addClass()` are jQuery methods.  The OP mentions nothing about using jQuery.

Comment: @Sparky, I have added none jquery as well.

Comment: This is an easily workable solution, thanks.  I am however still curious to know if there is a way to do this with :valid and :invalid pseudo-selectors rather than classes, or if that is not possible from JavaScript.